# Kivy VKeyboard object doesn't popup on request method

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to request a keyboard via Window method `request_keyboard()` in kivy however it doesn't assign the widget itself -> `self.keyboard.widget` is `None`. I read that it may be due to the wrong configuration in Config but I tried every configuration and my vkeyboard still doesn't popup. Am I missing something?
`self.show_keyboard()` doesn't work too.

```
class DataTextInput(TextInput, FocusBehavior):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DataTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            print("exists")
```

EDIT: ok I realized that `Window.allow_vkeyboard` flag was set to `False`, so it must be something wrong with Config.